# Displaying bin min and max range when saving NumPy histogram via savetxt

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, histogram

I've successfully constructed a basic histogram using NumPy, and I'm able to save it using `savetxt`.

What I haven't been able to figure out though is how to either modify the histogram itself, or `savetxt`, to output the bin range.

Rather than the output looking like this:

```
0.00 534
16.67 504
33.33 515
50.00 534
66.67 566
83.33 574
```

I'm looking for this:

```
0.00 16.66 534
16.67 33.32 504
33.33 49.99 515
50.00 66.66 534
66.67 83.32 566
83.33 (max?) 574
```

Code:

```
a = np.array(temperature_list)
freqs, bins = np.histogram(a, bins=5)
h = np.array(list(zip(bins,freqs)))
np.savetxt(
        fname=tsv_file,
        X=h,
        fmt='%1.2f %d',
        delimiter='\t')
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html?highlight=savetxt#numpy.savetxt seems pretty straight forward, so I'm assuming I'd need to somehow provide this as another array when creating the histogram? Perhaps preform a list comprehension of some kind as another item I'm constructing into `h`?

Comment: You could modify the `fmt` format string to three numbers and jointly save the bins and freqs. Something like `combined = [ (b[i], b[i+1], f[i]) for i in range(len(f))]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `bins`, the information is already there; `bins` is one element longer than `freqs`, but you cut the last bin border away by using `zip`, which iterates only over the smallest common length of its iterables.

Try e.g.

```
h = np.array(list(zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:], freqs)))
```